# SqlCeException: Expression evaluation caused an overflow

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

There are other questions with similar sounding titles, but my case appears to be unique, so here goes:

This problem seems to be centered on using Decimal values in my table. If I create a table and leave out the Precision and Scale parameters, the table creates but all of my data is inserted as an integer value. If I create a table and specify the Precision and Scale parameters, I get the exception thrown below my SQL Statements.

Here is my Create Table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE RMCoil 
(
    ID int IDENTITY (100,1) PRIMARY KEY
,   Modified DateTime NOT NULL
,   [Type] nchar(1)
,   [Model] nvarchar(50)
,   [CPPartNo] nvarchar(50)
,   [FH] decimal(10,10)
,   [FL] decimal(10,10)
,   [FPI] int
,   [TR] nchar(1)
,   [FinThk] decimal(10,10)
,   [FinMat] nchar(1)
,   [TubeOD] int
,   [Rifled] nchar(1)
,   [WallThk] decimal(10,10)
,   [CKT] int
,   [RD] int
,   [Split] nvarchar(50)
,   [CKT1] int
,   [CKT2] int
,   [CKT3] int
,   [CKT4] int
,   [Feed1] int
,   [Feed2] int
,   [Feed3] int
,   [Feed4] int
,   [Altitude] decimal(10,10)
,   [Connection] decimal(10,10)
,   [Header] decimal(10,10)
)
```

SqlCeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() returns -1, but this must be OK because it creates the table.

If a table exists, the SELECT statement works fine:

```
SELECT
    ID
,   Modified
,   [ID]
,   [MODIFIED]
,   [Model]
,   [VoltCode]
,   [Vendor]
,   [Product]
,   [ACRLA208SP]
,   [LRA208SP]
,   [ACRLA230SP]
,   [LRA230SP]
,   [ACRLA208]
,   [LRA208]
,   [ACRLA230]
,   [LRA230]
,   [ACRLA380]
,   [LRA380]
,   [ACRLA460]
,   [LRA460]
,   [ACRLA575]
,   [LRA575]
,   [ECRLA208]
,   [ECRLA230]
,   [ECRLA460]
,   [ECRLA575]
,   [Displacement]
,   [CF0]
,   [CF1]
,   [CF2]
,   [CF3]
,   [CF4]
,   [CF5]
,   [CF6]
,   [CF7]
,   [CF8]
,   [CF9]
,   [CF10]
,   [CF11]
,   [CF12]
,   [CF13]
,   [CF14]
,   [CF15]
,   [CF16]
,   [CF17]
,   [CF18]
,   [CF19]
,   [CF20]
,   [CF21]
,   [CF22]
,   [CF23]
,   [CF24]
,   [CF25]
,   [CF26]
,   [CF27]
,   [CF28]
,   [CF29]
,   [CF30]
,   [CF31]
,   [CF32]
,   [CF33]
,   [CF34]
,   [CF35]
,   [CF36]
,   [CF37]
,   [CF38]
,   [CF39] 
FROM RMCompressor
```

SqlCeCommand.CommandText.Length = 633

```
INSERT INTO RMCompressor
(
    Modified
,   [Model]
,   [VoltCode]
,   [Vendor]
,   [Product]
,   [ACRLA208SP]
,   [LRA208SP]
,   [ACRLA230SP]
,   [LRA230SP]
,   [ACRLA208]
,   [LRA208]
,   [ACRLA230]
,   [LRA230]
,   [ACRLA380]
,   [LRA380]
,   [ACRLA460]
,   [LRA460]
,   [ACRLA575]
,   [LRA575]
,   [ECRLA208]
,   [ECRLA230]
,   [ECRLA460]
,   [ECRLA575]
,   [Displacement]
,   [CF0]
,   [CF1]
,   [CF2]
,   [CF3]
,   [CF4]
,   [CF5]
,   [CF6]
,   [CF7]
,   [CF8]
,   [CF9]
,   [CF10]
,   [CF11]
,   [CF12]
,   [CF13]
,   [CF14]
,   [CF15]
,   [CF16]
,   [CF17]
,   [CF18]
,   [CF19]
,   [CF20]
,   [CF21]
,   [CF22]
,   [CF23]
,   [CF24]
,   [CF25]
,   [CF26]
,   [CF27]
,   [CF28]
,   [CF29]
,   [CF30]
,   [CF31]
,   [CF32]
,   [CF33]
,   [CF34]
,   [CF35]
,   [CF36]
,   [CF37]
,   [CF38]
,   [CF39])
 VALUES
(
    GetDate()
,   @Model
,   @VoltCode
,   @Vendor
,   @Product
,   @ACRLA208SP
,   @LRA208SP
,   @ACRLA230SP
,   @LRA230SP
,   @ACRLA208
,   @LRA208
,   @ACRLA230
,   @LRA230
,   @ACRLA380
,   @LRA380
,   @ACRLA460
,   @LRA460
,   @ACRLA575
,   @LRA575
,   @ECRLA208
,   @ECRLA230
,   @ECRLA460
,   @ECRLA575
,   @Displacement
,   @CF0
,   @CF1
,   @CF2
,   @CF3
,   @CF4
,   @CF5
,   @CF6
,   @CF7
,   @CF8
,   @CF9
,   @CF10
,   @CF11
,   @CF12
,   @CF13
,   @CF14
,   @CF15
,   @CF16
,   @CF17
,   @CF18
,   @CF19
,   @CF20
,   @CF21
,   @CF22
,   @CF23
,   @CF24
,   @CF25
,   @CF26
,   @CF27
,   @CF28
,   @CF29
,   @CF30
,   @CF31
,   @CF32
,   @CF33
,   @CF34
,   @CF35
,   @CF36
,   @CF37
,   @CF38
,   @CF39
)
```

**SqlCeException:** `Expression evaluation caused an overflow. [ Name of function (if known) =  ]`
**HResult:** `-2147217900`
**NativeError:** `25901`
**Source:** `SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider`

Does anyone know how to read the HResult or NativeError?

My INSERT statement isn't too long or something, is it?

If it helps, I've uploaded my Visual Studio 2010 C# project *SqlCeTool* (without the binaries) [>> HERE <<](http://sites.google.com/site/jp2code/home/list/SqlCeTool-0707.zip) (I will remove my project link after this issue is resolved).

Comment: Can you show us the schema of `RMCompressor` and values of `@ACRLA208SP`, `@LRA380`, `@CF0` and such?

Comment: There is no schema other than what is used to create the table in the `SQL` shown. This application takes an `Excel` worksheet and makes an attempt to insert it into an `SQL CE` table. The values could be anything. The `RMCompressor.csv` file is in the project linked above (which will eventually be removed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a decimal values with equal precision and scale, is that intended? As it stands, you are creating fields like Altitude which can contain values of .0000000000 to .9999999999 (assuming I counted right).  I believe you will want to adjust your precision and scale to be something like Altitude(20,10)

Books On Line article discussing [Precision, Scale, and Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)  Money quote: "Precision is the number of digits in a number. Scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point in a number. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2."

Comment: I'm trying to create something generic that can take whatever Engineering has in their `Excel` worksheet and create an `SQL` Table out of that. I only have 2 example files to work with, but it looks like their data goes to about 10 digits: `{99999999.99 to 9.999999999}`. That's 10 digits, so I coded for `Precision` of `10` and `Scale` of `10`. Did I misunderstand the SQL documentation?

Comment: OMG! I think setting the `Precision` to 20 fixed it. Hang on, let me check the actual table. It all inserted fine....

Comment: Yup, that was it! Thanks! BTW: On your profile, your blog website points to a dead link.

Comment: @jp2code Much appreciated on the dead link, I get confused on what handle I've used in places ;) I'll update the answer with a BOL reference to scale, precision and length but yeah, the precision is total digits, scale is digits after the decimal.